# Vertially align image and link on a single line

Tags: html, css

How do I align the following so that the image and the link are vertically aligned? Also how do I increase the spacing between consecutive lines?

```
<li><img src="c.png" alt="Centern | Karta"/> <a href="centern.php">Centern</a> </li>

<li><img src="fi.png" alt="Feministiskt initiativ | Karta"/><a href="feministiskt.php">Feministiskt initiativ</a> </li>
```

Comment: Do you know the height of the pngs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the images as background.

HTML

```
<li><a class='centern' href="centern.php" title="Centern | Karta">Centern</a> </li>
```

CSS

```
a.centern {
    background: url('c.png') no-repeat;
    height:20px; //height of the link
    width:100px; //width of the link
    padding-left:40px //give some space for the background image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirly sure what you mean by alignment. I set up a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GX5k6/

```
/* this takes care of the alignment of the text and images */
li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 32px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px; /* spacing between image and text */
}
li img {
    display: block;
    float: left;    
}
li {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;    
}
/* spacing between lines */
li {
   margin-bottom: 5px;   
}
```

Depending on wether you consider the images styling or content and if you want them to show up when the page is printed, you should indeed consider making them background images as suggested by @petar